# MS Access implenting hyperlink like behavior for records to switch between forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm currently working on a Database which requires the following functionality:

For example given a specific project, I have a series of structures which belong to that project, which are displayed in a datasheet view on the project form.  I am attempting to allow the user to on double click to navigate to that specific structure which is displayed on another form.  Currently I am using filters to implement this behavior, however, this results in the filter being left on, and when I manually turn off the filter, the form I switch to returns back to the first entry.

I am using the current code on the datasheet:

```
Private Sub struct_name_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

LookupValue = Me.struct_ID
Form_frm_control.pg_structure.SetFocus
Form_frm_control.subform_structure.Form.Filter = "struct_ID = " & LookupValue
Form_frm_control.subform_structure.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you need to do.

If you want to display all records and navigate to the selected record, then you can use bookmark navigation:

```
  With Forms!MyOtherForm
    .RecordsetClone.FindFirst "struct_ID = " & Me!struct_ID
    If Not .RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
       If .Dirty Then
          .Dirty = False
       End If
       .Bookmark = .RecordsetClone.Bookmark
    End If
  End With
```

This assumes that the other form is open with all the records loaded.

Another approach to this problem, which I find more useful for popup situations like this, is to just open the other form as a dialog and require it be closed before returning to the calling context. In that case, you'd do this:

```
  DoCmd.OpenForm "MyOtherForm", , , "struct_ID = " & Me!struct_ID, , acDialog
```

You'd then have to close the other form to get back to the original context.

You might think that with large numbers of records this would be inefficient, but it's actually very fast, as this operation is highly optimized within Access (moreso than filtering an already open form, in fact).